# Why only few parts of the 2D sprite change their colour when I apply sprite color in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, color

I'm making a stickman 2D game where I have different sprites for the player.

But when I try to change the Sprite Renderer Color, it only changes few pixels of the sprite and the rest stays black as in the original sprite.

What am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough information for an answer to this question. Could you provide some more details? What engine/framework are you using? What language? How are you changing the colour? Some pictures would be useful, as knowing which pixels are painted could identify the issue faster.

Comment: It's Unity. Sorry, I should have specified that. However, got my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mentioned that the rest of your pixels stay black. The way SpriteRenderer.Color is applied is via multiplication. The mentioned color field does not replace the pixel color but "tints" it. So if you have many black pixels in your sprite, they won't be affected because no matter what color you multiply black (0, 0, 0, 1) by it will remain black.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thank you! So that was what I was missing. If I edit my sprites and make them white, then it should work with the absolute colours I assume?

Comment: Yup, white will have the most pronounced effect.